# Google Static Map API specifically for HTML Email?

Tags: email, ampscript, html, map, google-map

Has anybody ever tried using Google Static Map API or something similar to generate dynamic map images to be used within HTML emails?

There's over 2k store locations and I'm wanting to avoid manually creating map images for each one. I'm hoping to use some sort of static map api that'll allow me to use the store address I'm pulling in from a data extension to populate a dynamic map image that's created at the time of send.

Any suggestions, tips or tricks is much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately `Google Static Map API` will soon be deprecated. However, implementation of it seems pretty straightforward. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/?hl=en) in an SFMC email before, but that's since been deprecated.  If there's a completely URL-based service (like [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) for example), sure, you can use it.   If it requires any kind of client-side JS, then I don't think it'd be possible.

Another option is to create your own web service outside of SFMC that returns an image.  You'll have a lot more flexibility that way.  Then you can just reference the images as the `src` or utilize the [httpget()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/#HTTPGet) AMPScript function to return data.